# CoyoteInputStream read method retuns 0

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I deployed my web application which expose some rest services in tomcat 6, but sometimes in the production  when application trying to read from input stream for POST type webservice, the input stream returning 0, Input stream is of type CoyoteInputSream, please check the part of code that i am using to read from input stream,

Below input is of type CoyoteInputStream provided by container.
`.

n = input.read(buffer);
// sometimes n is zero.      .`